# Gradient orientation with arctan2 results in flipped angles

Tags: numpy, opencv, matplotlib, computer-vision

I want to use `plt.quiver` to display arrows of the gradient of an array in the correct angle.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_array = np.array([[   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
                       [   0.,   64.,  128.,   64.,    0.],
                       [   0.,  127.,  255.,  127.,    0.],
                       [   0.,   64.,  127.,   64.,    0.],
                       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.]]).astype(np.float64)
dy,dx = np.gradient(test_array)
theta =np.degrees(np.arctan2(dy,dx))
print(theta)
color = np.sqrt(dy**2 + dx**2) 
plt.quiver(dx,dy,color)
plt.show()
```

However if I print `theta`:

```
[[   0.           90.           90.           90.            0.        ]
 [   0.           44.77531182   90.          135.22468818  180.        ]
 [   0.            0.          -90.          180.          180.        ]
 [   0.          -45.          -90.         -135.          180.        ]
 [   0.          -90.          -90.          -90.            0.        ]]
```

I can see that the angles in the first row are `[90,90,90]`
When I use `quiver` to plot the gradient I can see that the arrows are pointing in the opposite direction.

I would assume that the angles are displayed counter-clockwise but instead they are displayed clockwise. What am I missing? Can someone explain?

Comment: What do you mean `The arrows are pointing to the opposite direction`. What is your expected result?

Comment: as I said I would assume that if the angle is `90 degrees` then the arrow is facing in the positive y-axis (but it is facing towards the negative y-axis). If it would be `180 degrees` then I would expect that the arrow would face towards the negative x-axis. If the angle is `270 degrees` then I would expect the arrow would face towards the negative y-axis. Counter clockwise... (Note that coordinate system I see with the quiver function) looks like a normal cartesian coordiante system

Comment: Are you sure about the order of `dx` and `dy` returned by `np.gradient`?

Comment: `np.gradient` will calculate the gradient along the given axis of the image, so `axis=0=dy` will be rows and `axis=1=dx` will be columns. So I'am not 100% sure but it makes sense. Otherwise the angle is correct though, but then the arrows do not match to the real intensity change of the image.

Comment: According to documentation: `For two dimensional arrays, the return will be two arrays ordered by axis. In this example the first array stands for the gradient in rows and the second one in columns direction:` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html

Comment: yes so the order of `dy, dx` is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the array as if it is flipped up down when plotted by `plt.quiver`. You could see this by introducting an assymetry in your `test_array`. For example

```
test_array = np.array([[   0.,    0.,    20.,    50.,    0.],
                       [   0.,   64.,  128.,   64.,    0.],
                       [   0.,  127.,  255.,  127.,    0.],
                       [   0.,   64.,  127.,   64.,    0.],
                       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.]]).astype(np.float64)
```

Will be plotted as follows (notice the angles in `theta` and the angles of the arrows at the bottom of plot):

```
>>> print(theta)

[[   0.           81.11934085   76.96664367  125.53767779  180.        ]
 [   0.           44.77531182   90.          148.97046189  180.        ]
 [   0.            0.          -90.          180.          180.        ]
 [   0.          -45.          -90.         -135.          180.        ]
 [   0.          -90.          -90.          -90.            0.        ]]
```

[image]

Probably when you are looking at the `test_array` or `theta` you are thinking as if the origin is located at the top left corner. But the origin in matplotlib is at the bottom left.

Comment: probably the other way around but nice catch :)

Comment: To understand this compare how `plt.imshow` and `plt.pcolormesh` plot an array.